# conv2d does not work

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am training a CNN in tensorflow but the program seems to have stuck at the first tf.nn.conv2d step. I have imported the cifar 10 dataset from keras and running my code in floydhub. 
I haven't started the session yet, this is just the computation graph.
[Link to the complete notebook](https://github.com/aashishksahu/Deep-Learning/blob/master/CNN_CIFAR_10_Tensorflow_CPU.ipynb)

This is the part where it gets stuck:

```
# forward propagation

# convolution layer 1
c1 = tf.nn.conv2d(x_train, w1, strides = [1,1,1,1], padding = 'VALID')
# activation function for c1: relu
r1 = tf.nn.relu(c1)
# maxpooling
p1 = tf.nn.max_pool(r1, ksize = [1,2,2,1], strides = [1,2,2,1], padding = 'SAME')

# convolution layer 2
c2 = tf.nn.conv2d(p1, w2, strides = [1,1,1,1], padding='VALID')
# activation function for c2: relu
r2 = tf.nn.relu(c2) 
# maxpooling
p2 = tf.nn.max_pool(r2, ksize = [1,2,2,1], strides = [1,2,2,1], padding = 'SAME')

# flattening the previous max pool layer
l1 = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(p2)
# fully connected layer
final = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(l1, 10, activation_fn = None)
```

**EDIT:-**

**This is how I imported the dataset**

```
# importing 50000 images of size 32x32x3
i = 0
# this list holds the images
img_base = []
for img in glob.glob("train\\*.png"):
    img_base.append(cv2.imread(img))

# x_train is a nx32x32x3 matrix of n no. of images
x_train = np.array(img_base[0:40000]).astype(np.float32)
```

**placeholders for training images and labels**

```
# creating placeholders
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 32, 32, 3])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
```

**weight initialisation**`

```
tf.reset_default_graph()

# creating weights
w1 = tf.get_variable('w1', [4,4,3,10], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
w2 = tf.get_variable('w2', [4,4,10,15], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
```

Comment: What is the error message ?

Comment: @AkashGoyal no error message, it's just stuck.

Comment: How do you ensure that it is stucked at the mentioned line? Share how have you defined x_train, w1.

Comment: @AkashGoyal I have updated the question